# Can i3 CPU be bottleneck in gigabit network?

Tags: networking

Say I have 3.1Ghz i3 CPU on Ubuntu server. Can it be bottleneck in GB network reaching around 80-100MB/s throughput if Sata3 HDD has average/roughly 100MB/s r/w rate? Considering all cablings has max capabilities (cat6).

Comment: What research/steps have you taken to try to answer your own question?

Comment: Don't really have enough information. If you're transferring a lot of files from the Ubuntu server then it is most likely going to be the gigabit lan that is slowing you down. This CPU should not be the bottleneck. Only way it would be a bottleneck is if you're doing something processor intensive like queries in a database on the server.

Comment: wizlog: google!

Comment: kobaltz: no other work on CPU, solely transferring files over the network, similar to NAS.

Comment: You could have a virus scanner that is trying to scan while copying. That could cause slower than normal speeds. Also, you have to remember that transferring files over a lan is similar to transferring over USB. Those numbers are burst rates and not necessarily sustained.

Comment: What kind of switch do you have? Is it one that is built into your router or separate? I would look into firmware updates or something like openwrt/ddwrt to optimize your router if that is the case.

Comment: @kobaltz: dedicated 8 port gigabit switch. I am not going to run antivirus on Ubuntu )). The reason I asked this question is because I am going to change my server mobo to support sata3/gb and need to check whether the current i3 CPU is enough to support GB or not. If practically anyone knows that this is enough, but later I will not reach GB average, then I will look somewhere else, knowing that CPU is not the bottleneck.

Comment: You can check with different programs like Passmark benchmark software to test your gigabit network between two nodes. You will see whether or not your CPU is spiking.